# Why is the Unit Price showing up wrong for Bundled Products?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Take a look at this picture.  The Unit price is basically one of everything, but that is confusing to the users.  Is there a work around for displaying the actual cost of the product as the unit cost here:

[image]

I'm running magento 1.4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Probably because that's what the old cart did, or someone's created a customization that's altered the functionality.

1. Find the `phtml` template responsible for rendering that cart line
2. Remove the `echo` call that's rendering the current price
3. Replace it with the code that's outputting the total, **without** multiplying by quantity, **or** making sure to redivide by the quantity to get the unit price

Alternately, just find the `phtml` template that's rendering the Unit Price column and remove it.  Confusion avoided

(in case it needs to be said, you'll be adding a custom theme `phtml` file to replace the file in the base template)

Comment: It seems to be a problem with getCalculationPrice() and how bundled products handle that (or don't handle it for that matter)