# Magento Bundles: options price and qty

Tags: magento, product

**myBundle** is a bundled product and it has **myColorOption** with these items:

- Green $50 (Qty: 3)
- Blue $100 (Qty: 4)
- Red $100 (Qty: 0)
- Black $150 (Qty: 1)

The QTY is set by admin as default and cannot be changed by the customer.

How do i stop magento from multiplying the price with the quantity when a **myColorOption** is  added to the actual price in the cart

For example, if the customer selects option **Green $50 (Qty: 3)**. I want magento to just add 50$ to the price of **myBundle** product in the cart and not 50$*3

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes As i am using in one of my demo application you can set `price` in bundle option to `0.00`

for more information here i am attached screen shot which would very help to solve your issue..

[image]

so it will multiply with your sample product.

please let me know  if am wrong,

Comment: Hi Liyakat. I checked your suggestion and it does not work. The price remains 0 in this case and 5 item are being added to the chart. If it would work, then we would have to figure how to display the price for the bundled option. I would very much prefer a solution where it would't multiply the price.

Comment: do you have any idea where is this multiplication might takes place? i tried to find but it's very difficult to track it

Comment: you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920433/why-is-the-unit-price-showing-up-wrong-for-bundled-products